# Is it safe to use ptr in SPF?

Tags: spf, ptr-record

Suppose you have the domain `yourdomain.com`, and you have set the following SPF:

```
v=spf1 +ptr:yourdomain.com ~all
```

Now, I have the IP address 1.2.3.4, and I am also the administrator of `3.2.1.in-addr.arpa`. I can specify

```
4 IN PTR fake.yourdomain.com.
```

and then I can send emails from my machine, pretending it's one of the `yourdomain.com` machines.

Is this a significant risk? Should I avoid using ptr in the SPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to wikipedia using PTR will also forward confirm the PTR (IE 1.2.3.4 might resolve to fake.yourdomain.com but fake.yourdomain.com points to 5.4.3.2)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS

Comment: Thanks. See also http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax for a more reliable source.